# OpenGL Swapbuffers() behaves differently in OnCreate vs. in OnPaint, What is MFC doing?

Tags: opengl, mfc

I created an MFC single document interface application using MS Visual Studio 2013 and unselected most check boxes to simplify the autogenerated code. My view class inherits from CView, and it overrides OnCreate() and OnPaint(). I successfully create an OpenGL rendering context within OnCreate(), call glClearColor(), and glClear().  However, SwapBuffers() called from OnCreate() seems to do nothing, while calling it from OnPaint() paints the window's client area in the clearColor.

What is MFC doing between OnCreate and OnPaint that makes SwapBuffers() work?

```
int CMFCApplication1View::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    /* Most OpenGL context creation code removed */

    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, myOpenGLRenderContext); // Make the newly created OpenGL context current

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.9f, 0.0f); // Set the clear color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear buffers

    //SwapBuffers(hdc); // This line of code seems to do nothing.

    myHdc = hdc; // Save my HDC so I can call it from OnPaint

    return 0;
}

void CMFCApplication1View::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    //SwapBuffers(dc);
    SwapBuffers(myHdc); // The result is the same as using dc.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

MFC is doing nothing.  Why do you think it is?  MFC is simply a C++ wrapper around the Win32 API.  You might ask what the Win32 API is doing.

But, are you trying to paint in WM_CREATE (OnCreate() in MFC)?  I want to ask, why?  Normally, views are created invisible and then made visible.  Drawing in an invisible window does nothing useful.  When a part of a window gets invalidated, it needs to be redrawn.  Windows sends a WM_PAINT message when it needs to be repainted.  It makes no sense to draw in an invisible window.  Nothing happens.  As soon as the window is made visible, the whole window will be invalid and will be needed to be redrawn.

In general, with a CView derived class, you do not override OnPaint() or provide a handler for WM_PAINT.  Instead, you override OnDraw() which will be called by the framework in  response to a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: Something happened between WM_CREATE and WM_PAINT that allows SwapBuffers to have an effect. Whether it's ultimately done by Win32 or MFC isn't the point. What happened is.

Comment: Something happened between WM_CREATE and WM_PAINT that allows SwapBuffers to have an effect. Whether it's ultimately done by Win32 or MFC isn't the point. What happened is. (having problems with comment input, cant separate into paragraphs)   Why OnCreate? Because I am trying to figure out what happens and where in an MFC app.  Where might I get a step by step description of "views are created and made visible"? Your statement helps. As does "As soon as the window is made visible ...". The MSDN docs I've read haven't been clear on points like these.